# Compare disparate Date formats, which are stored as Strings

Tags: java

I have two disparate date formats presented in my application as strings. Here are the formats:

1. 07/01/2011
2. 2011-07-01

I'm looking for the most efficient way to assert their equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse both dates using `SimpleDateFormat` and then use the `equals()` method.

The formats to use will be `"MM/dd/yyyy"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date1 = format1.parse(value1);
Date date2 = format2.parse(value2);

return date1.equals(date2);
```

Comment: +1 for posting 30seconds ahead of me @Damokles same here but I didn't see his answer

Comment: Yea, was typing up similar solution when it flashed the 'new answers' banner on top of my screen. +1 for having fast fingers ;)

Comment: Seems like those typing classes during high school 20 years ago worked.

Comment: haha..u guys are like vultures trying to gain an easy 'score; :). thanks for replying so quick -

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to make them into `Dates` (or `Calendar` objects) and compare them like that.

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

MM is the month make sure they are capitalized.